# HTML Input - already filled in text

Tags: html, input, placeholder

I was wondering, is there a way to put text into an input field?
What i've got now is a placeholder, but that's actually an empty inputfield. So that's not what i'm looking for.
I'm looking for an (kind of) placeholder that's actually filled in into the input field, so not "background text"

This is with placeholder:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWY3y.png]

And this is what i want:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfGSy.png]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> The value content attribute gives the default value of the input element.
>
> <sup>- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value</sup>

To set the default value of an input element, use the `value` attribute.

```html
<input type="text" value="default value">
```

Answer (score 18):

All you have to do is use the value attribute of input tags:

```
<input type="text" value="Your Value" />
```

Or, in the case of a textarea:

```
<textarea>Your Value</textarea>
```

Answer (score 8):

You seem to look for the input attribute `value`, "the initial value of the control"?

```
<input type="text" value="Morlodenhof 7" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" value="Your value">
```

Use the `value` attribute for the pre filled in values.

Answer (score 3):

TO give the prefill value in HTML Side as below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="abc" value="any value">
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
  $("#abc").val('any value');
 });
```